# Application Gateway in Azure, back-end settings with multiple ports

Tags: azure, networking

I got a scenario where i have an app server that is hosting a webservice on two different ports on the same VM behind an application gateway. ie. 9443 and 9444.

From what i can tell there is no way i can have a single http listener and configure it in a way that would loadbalance between these different ports but i might be wrong.

Anyone encounterd a similar scenario like this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create an Application gateway with two different backend pool:

[image]

> ***Note*** that According to the [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/configuration-request-routing-rules#associated-back-end-http-setting) it is not possible to configure App gateway on basic listener, you need to use multi-site and also multiple backend http settings for the different ports.

For a basic rule, only one backend pool and one Http setting is allowed. All requests on the associated listener are forwarded to that backend pool and in HTTP setting all requests on the associated listener are forwarded to the corresponding backend targets. [**Refer**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-faq#can-one-backend-pool-serve-many-applications-on-different-ports)

Create two backend pool use muti-site listener like below.

[image]

An application gateway routes traffic to the backend servers by using the port number, protocol, and other settings.

[image]

You cannot add 2 different ports in a single HTTP setting, so you need 2 different HTTP setting with the 2 different ports and then bind them with listener and rule to access the application on 2 different ports.

Create two different rules and associate with each:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Using Application Gateway, many websites can share the same public IP address and port by using HTTP 1.1 host headers. The Server Name Indication (SNI) TLS extension can provide TLS offload for websites hosted on application gateways. To load balance traffic to the backend pool containing your app server, you must therefore construct two distinct HTTP listeners, one for each port.

[image]

To know more in detail, check these references.

[How a server in backend pool can listen on multiple ports using fqdn in Application Gateway -](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/513145/how-a-server-in-backend-pool-can-listen-on-multipl) by *gitarani sharama*

[Tutorial: Create and configure an application gateway to host multiple web sites using the Azure portal - Azure Application Gateway | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/create-multiple-sites-portal)